# Ionic 3: hide ion-footer on login page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have cloned the side-menu startproject and have this structure on my **app.html**:

```
<ion-menu [content]="content">
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
        {{p.title}}
      </button>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>

</ion-menu>

<ion-footer>
  <ion-toolbar>
        MYFOOTER
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>

<!-- Disable swipe-to-go-back because it's poor UX to combine STGB with side menus -->
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

I would like to be able to hide the footer on my login page, I tried these two things:

1. I created a variable on the Login Controller but the *ion-footer* is outside *ion-content* so I cannot access this variable (even with dot notation)
2. I created an external service with *global variables* and tried to access it from the footer but I wasn't able to

---

#### 1. Trying to access the variable of the LoginController

**login.ts**

```
...imports...

export class LoginPage {

    public login_data : any = {footerIsHidden: true}; 

    ...constructor & other stuff...
}
```

**app.html**

```
... 
<ion-footer *ngIf="!login_data.footerIsHidden" class="footer">
    MY FOOTER
</ion-footer>
...
```

I get an "*Cannot read property 'footerIsHidden' of undefined*" because I can't access the variable **login_data** on the **ion-footer tag**

#### 2. Create a service to manage global data

I create this service **global-data**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class GlobalDataService {
  public data:any = {};
}
```

I added it to my **app.module.ts**:

```
import { GlobalDataService } from '../services/global-data/global-data';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    ...
    GlobalDataService, <--- HERE
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
```

And I also added it on **main.ts**:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { GlobalDataService } from '../services/global-data/global-data';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule, [GlobalDataService]);
```

I read the last part was needed so the same service instance can be accessed anywhere.

If I inject the service on the *LoginController* I can set and get information there but again, I cannot access this service from the footer.

---

- Which is the best workaround for this ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suggest using `events` here.

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';

export class MyApp {
    public footerIsHidden: boolean = false;
    constructor(public events: Events) {
        events.subscribe('hideHeader', (data) => {
            this.footerIsHidden = data.isHidden;
        })
    }
}
```

**app.html**

```
<ion-footer *ngIf="!footerIsHidden" class="footer">
    MY FOOTER
</ion-footer>
```

**Login.ts**

```
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';

export class LoginPage {
    constructor(public events: Events) { 
       events.publish('hideHeader', { isHidden: true});
    }

    ionViewWillLeave() {
        //Make footer visiable while leaving the page.
        this.events.publish('hideHeader', { isHidden: false});
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Awesome, it works like a charm, the only thing is that you added the "footerIsHidden" public field outside the class MyApp, but it works like a charm. It was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks !

Comment: Insead of constructor its better to put event publish inside ionViewWillEnter. Because sometimes constructor runs before previous pages ionViewWillLeave lifecycle event.